# get id of self muted person in voice channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to get the User object of a person whenever they mute themselves in a voice channel using Discord.jS.

Example:

```js
if (somebody has muted themselves)
{
   const member = user.id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the [`Client#voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) event. It will fire whenever a voice state is updated. (This includes when a member mutes themselves.)

[`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) has a property called [`selfMute`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=selfMute) (boolean), which indicates if the member muted themselves. You can use [`serverMute`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=serverMute) to see if the member was server-muted.

---

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {
    if (oldVoiceState.selfMute !== newVoiceState.selfMute) {
        if (newVoiceState.selfMute) {
            console.log(`${newVoiceState.member.user.tag} muted themselves!`);
        };
    };
});
```